# Oracle APEX: scale image interactive report

Tags: oracle-apex

I use interative report in Oracle APEX 5.1 and would like to change the scale  and position of the image. The image appears in original size, and not in desired position. 
How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Probably with some CSS, but you'll need to supply more information about what you want. max-height can be a good property to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is a not desired position"? Wrong column? Rearrange them in the "Actions" menu IR offers.

As of the image *size*, you probably use something like this in your IR query; adjust it a little bit by adding `width` and/or `height`, such as in this example:

```
 DECODE (
    NVL (DBMS_LOB.getlength (s.image), 0),
    0, NULL,
       '<img src="'
    || APEX_UTIL.get_blob_file_src ('P200_IMAGE', s.id_image)
    || '" width="100" />')                                        --> this
    image
FROM my_images s ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works with the image size!